# Recursive function in a signature

Tags: first-order-logic, recursion

A first order language on real numbers has a symbol of  binary function $g: R \times R \rightarrow R$. The theory over this language needs to have a function $q$  which is interpreted as $q = \sum g(x_1, x_2)$ over all the domain of the function $g$. More generally, the theory has to have a function $q$ which depends on all the values of the function $g$. How would this function $q$ look in the signature? Its arity is not known: it depends on the model. Do I need to introduce another language to express this function $q$?

Edit 1: Can we even express recursion over an unordered set of real numbers? May be, the values of the function $g$ have to be ordered somehow?

Edit 2: Suppose, I need a  function which assigns a unique order number to each element of a finite set. Can this function be defined in logic somehow?

Comment: One way to do it: (1) introduce relationship $< $ on pairs of numbers in the finite domain; the theory can define it as a linear order; (2) introduce function `next' from pairs of numbers to pairs of numbers, the theory can define it through the relationship $<$; (3) introduce function ``first'' $0 \rightarrow $ (pair of numbers)  to identify the very first pair of numbers (4) $q(1) = first(0); q(i+1) = next(q(i)).$ This will count pairs.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want $q$ to be. Is the summation taken over all pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ of real numbers? If so, then in what sense is $q$ a function? And why does its arity depend on the model? Another example might be helpful.

Comment: @Karl The function $q$ from my comment is supposed to assigns a order number to each pair of elements $x_1, x_2$ in the domain. So, this will assign the same number for each value of the function $g(x_1, x_2).$ But now I need to have recursive function which sums up all the values of $g(x_1, x_2).$